# PHP PhantomJS on WAMP server: Fatal error: Uncaught exception

Tags: php, phantomjs

I am trying to use http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/, i just intaled it on WAMP and i run the [basic-request.php](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs/tree/master/examples)  but there is error: 
Any ideas what this error is and how to get around it?

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'JonnyW\PhantomJs\Exception\NotWritableException' with message 'File could not be written to system as target is not writable: /tmp/53dd3de26740c' in C:\wamp\www\Phantomjs\src\JonnyW\PhantomJs\Cache\FileCache.php on line 65**

Comment: Hi, this is an oversight on my behalf. The tmp dir set in `vendor/jonnyw/php-phantomjs/src/JonnyW/PhantomJS/Resources/config/config.yml` was meant as a fallback. This should have been overridden in the service container on load with the system tmp dir. I have now fixed this and tagged off a patch release v3.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with the new release. I edited `phantomjs.cache_dir:` in

> vendor/jonnyw/php-phantomjs/src/JonnyW/PhantomJS/Resources/config/config.yml

Change `phantomjs.cache_dir:` to your system's temp directory(as string) which can be found with `sys_get_temp_dir()`.

Comment: Hi, this is an oversight on my behalf. The tmp dir set in `vendor/jonnyw/php-phantomjs/src/JonnyW/PhantomJS/Resources/config/config.yml` was meant as a fallback. This should have been overridden in the service container on load with the system tmp dir. I have now fixed this and tagged off a patch release v3.1.1.